# Some Bootstrap icons not working on localhost?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, localhost, font-awesome

I'm trying to understand why `glyphicon-th-list` and `glyphicon-th` are not working.

I am building this on a local machine. I've noticed if I took the HTML and threw it on a server it works, confusing.

I don't get a [] type symbol. I get this:

[image]

If I change either of these to any other icon they seem to work fine. ('any' being any of the random ones I've attempted, haven't tested all).

I've re-downloaded and replaced the font files.

Some suggest disabling AdBlock, which is not a variable in this case

tested in FF, and Chrome.

Comment: See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13657

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the culprit is with the font-size of the icon you're displaying. Check out this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/o5dz2r34/2/

Notice that when the font-size is increased on the second two sets of images with the following CSS class:

```
.font-size-2x {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

they appear as expected. So, try increasing the font-size to a desired size that will show them as expected.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I set it to 1.1em and it works fine. Weird that it only acts that way for presumably these two icons but whatever. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, that rendering is sometimes a "feature" of vector graphics. Here's a link to a comparison page of different vector graphics packages: http://tagliala.github.io/vectoriconsroundup/. I personally like Font Awesome.